# Creating methods that follow/unfollow other models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations, join

I have a relationship setup where a User can follow multiple celebrities.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :celebrities, :through => :following
end

class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :celebrity
end

class Celebrity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :following
end
```

What I'd like to do is create methods that would allow users to: follow/unfollow a celebrity, indicate if the user is following the celebrity. Also in the user model I want to show the list of celebrities they're following and in the celebrity model show the users following them. I've attempted to do so for the first two methods but wasn't 100% sure how to go about writing the rest.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def follow(celebrity)
    followings.create(celebrity_id: celebrity.id)
  end

  def unfollow(celebrity)
    followings.find_by(celebrity_id: celebrity.id).destroy
  end

  def following?(celebrity)
  end

  def follows
  end
end

class Celebrity < ActiveRecord::Base
  def followers
  end
end
```

Am I on the right track with this? Also, what would be the best way to ensure that a user can only follow a celebrity **once** to prevent an additional `followings` instance from being created?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, follow & unfollow actions are not supposed to be in user model rather in users_controller.

Comment: I was attempting to follow how its done in this tutorial (which he uses those two methods in the join table's controller: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users

Comment: Definitely, you are supposed to do it in controller, not in model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate that user can follow celebrity only one, you can add uniq validation to Following model, like

```
class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :celebrity

  validates :celebrity_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings
  has_many :celebrities, through: :followings

  def follow(celebrity)
    followings.create(celebrity_id: celebrity.id)
  end

  def unfollow(celebrity)
    followings.find_by(celebrity_id: celebrity.id).destroy
  end

  def following?(celebrity)
    celebrity.followers.find_by(id: id).present?
  end

  def follows
    celebrities
  end
end

class Celebrity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings
  has_many :users, through: :followings

  def followers
    users
  end
end
```

And don't forget to add uniq index in the database

Comment: Would you happen to know how to correctly write the other three methods from the two models?

Comment: Added some code, it is actually a simple has_many through relation.

Comment: Thanks. Two things I noticed while experimenting with your solution. The first being that I needed to add a `bang` to the `follow` method to get it to work in the console. Additionally the 'following?` method doesn't work. This is the error message: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.user_id'`.

Comment: I'm not sure that bang is necessary, it is just a style preference to focus developer, that method mutates its object.
I've fixed following? method, check it out.

If my answer helped you - feel free to mark it as accepted(green check mark near score) :)

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin, why did you make follow and unfollow instance method? They are suppose to be in users_controller?

Comment: @Sharvy Ahmed, Actually OP did them an instance method. I think this is good decision. Because you will call them in controller, like @user.follow(celebrity)